# Disassemling a Win32 DLL with symbols

Tags: winapi, assembly, reverse-engineering

I've scoured Google and found to large a variety of tools and answers.  I want to disassemble a DLL into something at least readable, e.g. recognise Win32 API calls by their names etc.  How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [THIS](http://programmerstools.org/taxonomy/term/25). Any of them can work for you but IDA rocks...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are the [Windows Symbol Packages](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/symbolpkg.mspx). When you install these, you're basically getting symbol information (debugging info) for the majority of the Windows API, including Kernel32 and advapi (which I find to be the two biggies in my programming).

You might need to tell your debugger and/or compiler where the symbols live though - just make sure you remember where they install to, then you can use a debugger option (sometimes called "sympath") to tell the debugger where to find them.